# Joomla conditional language display

Tags: php, joomla

I try to display a field depending on joomla language

I tried many versions like this but didnt succeded.

```
<?php 

$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
if($lang == 'ro-ro') {
echo 'Current language is: ' . $lang->getTag(); 
}
?>
```

I need a code for 3 languages.When is romanian to display an message when is english another message , and on french 3rd different message.

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you

Comment: What is the result? What else have you tried?

Comment: Shouldn't that be 'ro-RO'?

Comment: In which version of Joomla ?

Comment: I solved this problem , i found the solution on other question here.And yes is ro-RO...i tried the posted code as i follow the developer of the component, but the code was not good.